# Web scraping in python returns "None"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** something from a site using python. For example the views on this video (the url) it always returns "None". What am I doing wrong? here is the code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OfK8UmLMl0&ab_channel=HitraNtheUnnecessaryProgrammer'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
views = soup.body.find(class_='view-count style-scope ytd-video-view-count-renderer')
print(views)
```

Thanks!
(btw when I try the code shown in the video it works fine)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

The page is loaded dynamically, `requests` doesn't support dynamically loaded pages. However, the data is available in JSON format, you can use the `re`/`json` modules to get the correct data.

For example, to get the "view count":

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OfK8UmLMl0&ab_channel=HitraNtheUnnecessaryProgrammer"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

# We locate the JSON data using a regular-expression pattern
data = re.search(r"var ytInitialData = ({.*?});", soup).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

print(
    data["contents"]["twoColumnWatchNextResults"]["results"]["results"]["contents"][0][
        "videoPrimaryInfoRenderer"
    ]["viewCount"]["videoViewCountRenderer"]["viewCount"]["simpleText"]
)
```

Output:

```
124 views
```

---

The variable `data` contains all the data in a Python dictionary (`dict`) to print all the data you can use:

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output (truncated):

```
{
    "responseContext": {
        "serviceTrackingParams": [
            {
                "service": "CSI",
                "params": [
                    {
                        "key": "c",
                        "value": "WEB"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "cver",
                        "value": "2.20210701.07.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "yt_li",
                        "value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "GetWatchNext_rid",
                        "value": "0x1d62a299beac9e1f"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "service": "GFEEDBACK",
                "params": [
                    {
                        "key": "logged_in",
                        "value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "e",
                        "value": "24037443,24058293,24058128,24003103,24042870,23882685,24023960,23944779,24027649,24046896,24059898,24049577,23983296,23966208,24056265,23891346,1714258,24049575,24045412,24003105,23999405,24051884,23891344,23986022,24049573,24056839,24053866,24058240,23744176,23998056,24010336,24037586,23934970,23974595,23735348,23857950,24036947,24051353,24038425,23990875,24052245,24063702,24058380,23983813,24058812,24026834,23996830,23946420,24001373,24049820,24030040,24062848,23968386,24027689,24004644,23804281,24049569,23973490,24044110,23884386,24012512,24044124,24059521,23918597,24007246,24049567,24022729,24037794"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "service": "GUIDED_HELP",
                "params": [
                    {
                        "key": "logged_in",
                        "value": "0"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "service": "ECATCHER",
                "params": [
                    {
                        "key": "client.version",
                        "value": "2.20210701"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "client.name",
                        "value": "WEB"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "mainAppWebResponseContext": {
            "loggedOut": true
        },
        "webResponseContextExtensionData": {
            "ytConfigData": {
                "visitorData": "CgtoanprT1pPbmtWTSjYk46HBg%3D%3D",
                "rootVisualElementType": 3832
            },
```

Comment: Just a heads up that this code no longer works (as YouTube is constantly changing their site). The `re.search` line gives `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.
You can fix it (for now) by changing `data = re.search(r"var ytInitialData = ({.*?});", soup).group(1)` to `data = re.search(r"var ytInitialData = ({.*?});", soup.prettify()).group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to view the API requests (from the network tab on dev tools) when a site is dynamically loaded. I was successful with sites such as udemy, skillshare and few others but not with youtube. so in such case, I would use the youtube official API. which is quite easy to use and have plenty of code samples on [github](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python). with that you just request your data and get a json response. that you can convert to a dictionary with `response.json()`. or another option would be using selenium which is not a solution I like and it's pretty resource and time consuming. requesting from API is faster than scraping or any other solution on earth. when something doesn't provide an API, you need scraping